# Calculate the outermost coordinates from an array

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, coordinates

I would like to draw a rectangle over a google map and this rectangle should be group some countries' border. 
For example, if I take the NE & SW coordinates of France, Italy and Switzerland I have to calculate which are the outermost value, in terms of NE and SW; the upper-left point should be from France and the bottom-right should be from Italy.

This is my array:

```
var arr = new Array();
arr.push(new coordinate(13.9918383, 9.19871231));
arr.push(new coordinate(11.2215083, 9.23882110));
```

How can I calculate those values from an array of coordinates?

[image]

Comment: Do you have an example array with your coordinates so we can see what data you are working with and how its structured?

Comment: yes, I've updated the code

Comment: Where do the coordinates come from?  What is a `coordinate` (its not part of the Google Maps Javascript API v3)? Sounds like you want [LatLngBounds.union](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds)

Comment: These comes from the google json (es. https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=France)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the maximum and minimum values by looping over the array, and comparing the values of your coordinates.

```
function coordinate(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

var arr = new Array();
arr.push(new coordinate(13.9918383, 9.19871231));
arr.push(new coordinate(11.2215083, 9.23882110));


var maxN, maxS, maxE, maxW, ne, sw;

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(maxN == undefined) { maxN = arr[i].y; }
    if(maxS == undefined) { maxS = arr[i].y; }
    if(maxE == undefined) { maxE = arr[i].x; }
    if(maxW == undefined) { maxW = arr[i].x; }


    //check NE
    if(arr[i].y <= maxN && arr[i].x >= maxE) {
        maxN = arr[i].y;
        maxE = arr[i].x;
        ne = arr[i];
    }
    //check SW
    if(arr[i].y >= maxS && arr[i].x <= maxW) {
        maxS = arr[i].y;
        maxW = arr[i].x;
        sw = arr[i];
    }

}

console.log('Furthest NE position is: '+ne.x + ', '+ne.y);
console.log('Furthest SW position is: '+sw.x + ', '+sw.y);
```

You can see it working in this JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9w1aLxkk/1/

Hope that helps!